# Parsing XML Document with Python - Search specific Elements, get String inside

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I got a XML-Doc with the following structure:

```
<defaults> 
<options>
<param name="userMail">user@mail.org</param>
<param name="adminMail"admin@mail.org</param>
<param name="language">en</param>
<param name="country">EN</param>
<> ... </> 
</defaults>
</options>
```

Inside the "options"-Tag I got a lot of param-Elements, I want to search for the "userMail" and "adminMail" element.

```
    tree = ET.parse("file_config.xml")
    root = tree.getroot()
    for admin in root.iter("param"):
    print(admin.text)
```

This works great, but I get the whole output (user@mail.org, admin@mailorg, en, EN).

How can I search only for the "userMail" and "adminMail" element and store each in a single variable?

I use xml.etree.ElementTree as ET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below (do the same for the user mail)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<defaults>
   <options>
      <param name="userMail">user@mail.org</param>
      <param name="adminMail">admin@mail.org</param>
      <param name="language">en</param>
      <param name="country">EN</param>
   </options>
</defaults>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
admin_mail = root.find('.//param[@name="adminMail"]').text
print(admin_mail)
```

output

```
admin@mail.org
```